# How to resize a big image to cover whole div using HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to place an image as background to a div. The image size is 5568x3712 but still the `background-size: contain` does not place the whole image as the background. See the below screenshot:
[image]

The image is not covering the right side of the div. Below is my CSS code:

```
.heroSection{
  background-image: url('../../public/hero-section.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-color: rgb(148, 145, 145);
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

I don't know why it's not covering the whole div. I researched and tried `background-size: contain` and `background-repeat:no-repeat` but is there any better alternative that can help me to get the desired result?

### EDIT

As per the response as well after lots of experimentation and research, it's not possible to fit a large image properly to a small div as a background. You need to make it of the appropriate size to cover it properly. Thanks to @somethinghere and @koala Yeung

Comment: Maybe use `background-size: cover` if you want it to _cover_, you know. And have a look at the web docs at least: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: first, try to find the solutions If you can't then ask to SO community, this is not the proper way to use SO.

Comment: You can change the aspect ratio of the background image by specifying the size with CSS "background-size: <width> <height>"

Comment: You can't have the image cover the whole div and not be cropped, you cannot fit a rectangle into a square and not crop the rectangle!

Answer (score 1):

It is expected. You may reference the MDN document about different [background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).

If you want the image to cover the whole HTML div, you can use "background-size: cover" instead. The down side is that unless the div is exactly the same size as the div, part of the image will be outside of the div.

contain
[image]

cover
[image]

If you simply want the image to cover your whole element but you're not concern about distortion, you may choose to use `background-size: 100% 100%`.

background-size: 100% 100%.
[image]

If you are concern about the image distortion while still want the image to cover the whole div, you need to change your div's size to fit the image's aspect ratio.

Given that your div fills 100% of the screen width and your image is 5568 x 3712, you may set the div to fixed height 66.6667% of view width

```html
<style>
.my-background {
  height: 66.6667vw;
  background-image: url('../../public/hero-section.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  ...
  ...
}
</style>
<div class="my-background"></div>
```

Comment: The cover fits the image but also crops the extra image. I don't want my image to be cropped.

Comment: As I described in the answer, this is expected. Logically speaking, if the div has a different aspect ratio than the background image, either you cut the image (cover), or it just fit the inner bound to show the whole image (contain), or you need to distort the image. Which do you prefer?

Comment: Looks like there's some trade offs. I followed your suggested solution and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
yourelement{
background: url(yourimage.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover; 
}
```

Comment: The cover fits the image but also crops the extra image. I don't want my image to be cropped.

Comment: There then? ```yourelement {
  background: url(yourimage.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: auto;
  background-size: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
}```